# Why is a synchronizer supporting shared acquisition acquired exclusively?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*, in "14.5 AbstractQueuedSynchronizer", it says:

> A synchronizer supporting exclusive acquisition should implement the protected methods `tryAcquire`, `tryRelease`, and `isHeldExclusively`, and **those supporting shared acquisition should implement `tryAcquireShared` and `tryReleaseShared`**. The `acquire`, `acquireShared`, `release`, and `releaseShared` methods in AQS call the `try` forms of these methods in the synchronizer subclass to determine if the operation can proceed. The synchronizer subclass can use `getState`, `setState`, and `compareAndSetState` to examine and update the state according to its `acquire` and `release` semantics, and informs the base class through the return status whether the attempt to acquire or release the synchronizer was successful. For example, returning a negative value from `tryAcquireShared` indicates acquisition failure; **returning zero indicates the synchronizer was acquired exclusively**; and returning a positive value indicates the synchronizer was acquired nonexclusively. The `tryRelease` and `tryReleaseShared` methods should return true if the release may have unblocked threads attempting to acquire the synchronizer.

I don't quite understand those two bold sentences.

- A synchronizer supporting **shared** acquisition should implement `tryAcquireShared` and `tryReleaseShared`.
- returning zero from `tryAcquireShared` indicates the synchronizer was acquired **exclusively**.

**Why is a synchronizer supporting shared acquisition acquired exclusively?**

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizer may support both exclusive and shared acquisition - in this scenario returning 0 from tryAcquireShared makes sense. According to `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` docs:

> Usually, implementation subclasses support only one of these modes,
>   but both can come into play for example in a ReadWriteLock. Subclasses
>   that support only exclusive or only shared modes need not define the
>   methods supporting the unused mode.